# How can I evaluate the complexity of two solutions when both additions and multiplications are present?

Tags: algorithms

I am evaluating FFTs algorithms radix-2/4 and split radix. (although this talk can be applied to any algorithm).

Each of them has a certain amount of complex additions and multiplications.
That can also be expressed in terms of real operations, but that does not solve the problem: in the end I have apples and pears and I cannot add them, so I cannot actually say which one is "cheaper".

One way to obtain a single cost number is to estimate the cost of a multiplication and addition and toss these coefficients in the initial formulas. But this requires additional knowledge which I don't want to include, as it greatly depends on the technology used.

**So my question is: is there any meaningful way to compare the complexity of two solutions expressed in terms of multiplications and additions?**

I thought of using an average (arithmetic, geometric, quadratic..) but then I wouldn't know how to motivate my decision.

I also thought of defining the amount of bit of the operands used in all the operations, say W. From this, I know that a multiplication where both operands have W bit, can be seen as W additions of the same shifted operands, so `1 multiplication = W additions`. But would this make sense?

Comment: Measure complexity as a duple rather than a scalar.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I essentially agree with Markus Mueller’s answer but you really should not let it get in your way. All the legacy complexity numbers used multiplications as a basis because a multiply on a fixed point ALU with add, subtract, and bit shift took a lot of cycles compared to just about every else. Modern processors have different bottle necks but from a Joule per operation perspective, a multiply remains expensive and heat dissipation and battery drain is a significant constraint

Comment: "cheaper" implies a cost function.  You haven't specified your cost function: FPGA macroblocks, NAND gates, gate delays, joules of switching current, processor cycles of a 6502 or Core i9, Turing machine tape length, et.al.  Which one?  Different cost functions will produce a very different result.

Comment: I explicitly said that I don't want to take the implementation platform into consideration.

Comment: Are you familiar with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFTW)? Would ways of actually measuring performance be of any use to you?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: No. On most CPU platforms, a) there's combined multiply-accumulate and vectorized math instructions that make a direct conversion impossible and b) the number of operations tells you little to nothing about how efficiently they execute in an unknown implementation of the algorithm.

(Also: There's a difference between a theoretical algorithm and its implementation. It's quite a decisive difference.)

> So my question is: is there any meaningful way to compare the complexity of two solutions expressed in terms of multiplications and additions?

I maintain that: no.

Well, let's be a bit more specific: Knowing whether either of one grows exponentially, logarithmically, polynomial… is relevant for very large problems to compare the *ideas* of different algorithms.

None of that will tell you much about how these compare in the real world.

First thing first: You forget to mention what your objective is. Is it implementing said FFT on e.g. a silicon chip or FPGA not exceeding a specific amount of semiconductor size? Is it implementation on a single-core CPU with uncached SRAM (a small microcontroller)? Is it implementation on a multicore CPU with pipelining, all kinds of caches and speculative execution? Or is it going to run on a manycore thing (e.g. a GPU)?

All these set very different boundaries.

For example, take your FPGA: An "adder" has, if I remember correctly, a number of gates defined linearly by the amount of bits you're adding. A single-clock multiplier will take much more gates (quadratically). However, if you just need to multiply by 2, that's a non-operation: your synthesizer simply connects the wires differently to the next input, implementing a bitshift without any time or complexity cost.

On the other hand, that doesn't matter at all, because FPGAs on which you'd do math would normally have so-called DSP slices, and those are basically Arithmetic logical units inside your FPGA that are much faster than FPGA fabric at adding and multiplying things. Some can do both at the same time (multiply-accumulate), others one and then the other… However, you only have a few of these slices, so you'd design your algorithm to fit your hardware; that's why you use the FFT that comes from your FPGA manufacturer, and not some random radix-2 implementation you found on the internet.

Then, look at your CPU: If you're designing and FFT to run on x86_64, my wild guess is you're going to use floating point numbers (something you'd usually avoid in an FPGA). For floating point, at least theoretically, addition is harder than multiplication. Doesn't matter, for both there's instructions that work in a few CPU cycles. Furthermore, if you can restructure your algorithm to do e.g. 8 multiplications at once, there's a special instruction that does that just as fast as doing a single one – suddenly, the number of multiplications becomes less important than how many you can do at once!

Things get even more convoluted. Rule of thumb says that RAM is typically 100–1000 times slower than the FPU. I.e., if you need to fetch a single number from RAM, you can do 200 floating point operations in the time you're waiting.  Obviously, that's quite catastrophic, so you try to hide RAM latency as good as your algorithm allows you to, make sure that all numbers you will use are in the same RAM bank (because your RAM doesn't deliver only a single word at once, but a full bank), and that your RAM access pattern is linear, so that automatic precaching works "magically" for you.

Here, things get a little complex:

Well, you see, CPUs have pipelines: A single CPU instruction needs to be fetched (e.g. from RAM), then needs to be decoded, then we need to set up a few things (e.g. make sure the FPU is ready if it's an FPU instruction), then the individual unit does its work, which typically takes more than one clock cycle, then the result need to be written to one or multiple registers and/or RAM.
That's a lot of stuff happening to one instruction, and because that stuff happens sequentially, most of the CPU doesn't do anything at any time. To avoid that, the moment the first instruction is fetched, the next can be fetched, the moment the first instruction is decoded, the next can be decoded … and so on. That way, it doesn't matter if an instruction takes 24 clock cycles to execute, if you have 24 pipeline stages, you get about one finished instruction per cycle.

Now, that's all fine and dandy, unless one instruction depends on the output of another one. So, your multiplication of two values that were already calculated a long time ago is nearly "free", because you don't have to wait for anyone, but if you want to then multiply the result of that by 3.1416 right after, well, your pipeline needs to wait for the first multiply instruction to finish so that the second can start. So, ordering becomes way more important than the type of operation (it really is; it's SO much important, that modern CPU look at multiple instructions at once and try to reorder them if possible, to avoid such pipeline stalls. That's some freaky execution dependency graph processing going on there).

Oh, things get a little complicated once you're there: Algorithms typically have something like "do this to all your $N$ input values". In an FPGA, you'd do that parallely (if your space allows), in a CPU using a loop. But loops are essentially jumps in the code and branches (if iwaste energy by speculatively executing up to five branching instructions – that's a tree of possible "go left or right" decision with 32 leaves – just to be able to have calculated the result you will get **if** you take the right hand side; there's side effects to that. Maybe you've heard of Meltdown/Spectre).

At this point, we might need to talk about things getting a little involved: You see, more than one process uses your CPU, and there's an operating system switching between your task and things like making sure data at some point reaches your SSD/hard drive. You see, that happens by interrupting your code, jumping somewhere else entirely, doing some processing, potentially flushing out the memory you were using out of CPU caches, and then restoring the CPU state and jumping back to you. Or maybe, jump to your code, but on a different CPU core. Since you're comparing FFTs on a modern computer, you definitely are using multithreading, so you'd look into these context changes working as smoothly as possible.

You see, reducing real-world performance to one or two numbers about an algorithm, not even its implementation, can't work, because it ignores the hardware it needs to run on.